# Applying databinding adapter to include tag

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm using databinding in my project and I have one for setting a visibility condition from the viewmodel:

```
<View
   app:visibilityCondition="@{viewModel.showingItems}" />
```

This all works fine, but suddenly when I want to use it on an include tag like this:

```
<include
   layout="@layout/my_include_layout
   app:visibilityCondition="@{viewModel.showingItems}" />
```

It doesn't build, with the following error:

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
>   Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:visibilityCondition' with parameter type boolean on com.example.CustomBinding.

Since the `CustomBinding` class doesn't actually extend from `View`, but instead `ViewDataBinding`, it doesn't look like I have a way to do this.

Is there a way around that, or am I forced to set the visibility of this included layout programatically? I know that will work, but I'd really like to keep it within the databinding if possible.

Comment: Did you get the answer ?

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, currently you are not able to use `BindingAdapters` with `included` layout elements, but you can pass your variables inside the included layouts (for them to handle).

What [Keshav Aggarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50747576/1993204) proposed is almost ok. You will have to **pass the data inside the `included` layout**, but exposing the whole `ViewModel` inside the layout is unnecessary and a bit inelegant.

1. Modify the `my_include_layout`, adding a variable with the bound parameter.

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="visibilityCondition"
            type="<the_type_of_the_visibility>"/>
    </data>
    <View
        app:visibilityCondition="@{visibilityCondition}"/>
</layout>
```

2. Use `bind` namespace to pass the visibility parameter inside the `included` layout:

```
<include
   layout="@layout/my_include_layout
   bind:visibilityCondition="@{viewModel.showingItems}" />
```

Comment: Nice Solution @Bartek Lipinski

Answer (score 2):

So, there is some catch if you want Data Binding to work when you are using `include` in your layouts, So do these things:

**Step 1**: Change your xml file in which you are using `include` tag to something like this. Look closely how i am playing with the variable names in this Data Binding.

```
<data>
     <import type="com.example.jenny.MyViewModel"/>
     <variable
         name="viewModelNew"
         type="MyViewModel"/>

      <include
         layout="@layout/my_include_layout
         app:viewModel="@{viewModelNew}"/> <!--this, viewModel is the variable declared in xml which you are including here-->
</data>
```

**Step 2**: And in the layout which you are including i.e. in `my_include_layout`, do the Real Data Binding there like this:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.jenny.MyViewModel"/>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="MyViewModel"/>
</data>

  <View
     app:visibilityCondition="@{viewModel.showingItems}"/><!--the real Data Binding is happening here-->
```

**Step 3**: Also, in your activity or fragment, where ever you are initializing Data Binding, do write

```
dataBinding.viewModelNew = new MyViewModel() // or something like this, you have to initialze the data binding variable
```

Let me know, if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your included layout still sets visibility condition based on `viewModel` as shown in your first code snippet and that it must then have a `<data>` section that defines `viewModel`, what I usually do is set that in the `include` statement. For example:

```
<include
    bind:viewModel="@{viewModel}"
    layout="@layout/my_include_layout"/>
```